# CSS code alignment (html and CSS3)

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me in aligning the List, i want the text to be displayed in same margin as on the first line.

List styling image

[image: List styling image]

Comment: I have used the below code:

Comment: post your code pls

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: I have given the code below can you check that please.

Comment: please edit your code directly into the question body, rather than linking to an external website or posting code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Now you see me..

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.list {
    background-color: #EA7125;
}

.list-item {
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
}

.list-item > p {
    margin-left: 85px; /* this line do the trick */
}

.order {
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
        <span class="order"></span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem nisi aspernatur, veniam quidem perferendis quisquam perspiciatis vel cupiditate nam. Est alias quis ipsam id rem. Ut deserunt recusandae fugit quam!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate nostrum eos facilis labore quisquam totam, soluta repellat deleniti inventore. Id sed enim ratione. Soluta dolorum, maxime expedita obcaecati sapiente distinctio!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="list-item">
        <span class="order"></span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa fugiat eveniet sapiente saepe non ullam iste, incidunt nesciunt voluptatibus sunt soluta molestiae quaerat beatae cupiditate aut, necessitatibus dolores iusto at?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the below code

```
ul li{
   list-style-type: disc;
   list-style-position: outside;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/selvassn/x0nx5fts/